# Two accounts with the same email - Watson Studio Desktop

Tags: watson-studio

Two accounts with same email ?
Message body: I receive the following message t appears that another account with this email already has this trial. If you think this is incorrect, please contact IBM Marketplace support and provide the code BZSMS1134E. I have no two ibm cloud ids with the same email. I tried to activate Watson Studio Desktop.

I have a problem to activate the Watson Studio Desktop for IBMers in addition I'm not able to avtivate the Watson Studio DEsktop Trial. I think there is a wrong linkage in the licence database "two IBMIDs with the same email"

Comment: Error Occurred

It appears that another account with this email already has this trial. If you think this is incorrect, please contact IBM Marketplace support and provide the code BZSMS1134E.

Answer (score 0):

Try logging in schoppi id, instead of your email address.